# Может ли быть на входе для алгоритма Беллмана-Форда граф, состоящий из ДВУХ вершин?

Tags: алгоритм

Может ли быть на входе для алгоритма Беллмана-Форда граф, состоящий из ДВУХ вершин?
Если да, то как обрабатывать этот случай?

Comment: какая связь с `c#`?

Answer (score 1):

Может даже из 1.

Псевдокод алогоритма (http://e-maxx.ru/algo/ford_bellman)

```
void solve() {
vector<int> d (n, INF);
d[v] = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n-1; ++i)
    for (int j=0; j<m; ++j)
        if (d[e[j].a] < INF)
            d[e[j].b] = min (d[e[j].b], d[e[j].a] + e[j].cost);
// вывод d, например, на экран
}
```

При N = 1 итераций вообще не будет.
При N = 2 мы проверим единственное ребро (если оно конечно есть, `1-->2`) и если есть установим в `d[2] = len(1->2)`.

Специально ничего менять не надо. Если у вас что-то не так проверьте реализацию.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39911/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel---------).